# PHP Remote Streaming Not Working On iOS (Safari, Chrome)

Tags: php, ios, safari

I found this code laying around on the web some time ago to stream remote video files through my server and it works perfectly except on iOS (iPhone 6S, iOS 12.4). Went to tons of threads that recommended having the 'Accept-Ranges', 'Content-Length' and the 'Content-Type' headers, which are already implemented in the code. iOS is refusing to stream the file, both on Safari and Chrome.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT #1**

Apparently my server is not returning ranges correctly. Apple usually asks first for partial content like "Range: bytes=0-1". Currently it's stuck waiting for a response from the code. Also verified that it isn't working on Safari for macOS. Oh Apple.

```php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36";
$v = 'https://notmywebsite/remotevideo.mp4';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 222222);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $v);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$info = curl_exec($ch);
$size2 = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);

$filesize = $size2;
$offset = 0;
$length = $filesize;

header("Content-Type: video/mp4");

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    $partialContent = "true";
    preg_match('/bytes=(\d+)-(\d+)?/', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches);
    $offset = intval($matches[1]);
    $length = $size2 - $offset - 1;
} else {
    $partialContent = "false";
}
if ($partialContent == "true") {
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Content-Range: bytes '. $offset .
        '-' . ($offset + $length) . 
        '/'. $filesize);
} else {
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
}

header("Content-length: ". $size2);

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    // if the HTTP_RANGE header is set we're dealing with partial content
    $partialContent = true;
    // find the requested range
    // this might be too simplistic, apparently the client can request
    // multiple ranges, which can become pretty complex, so ignore it for now
    preg_match('/bytes=(\d+)-(\d+)?/', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches);
    $offset = intval($matches[1]);
    $length = $filesize - $offset - 1;
    $headers = array(
        'Range: bytes=' . $offset . 
        '-' . ($offset + $length) .
        ''
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 222222);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $v);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: did you get this to work?

Comment: Yes, yes I did. Just posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a solution. The code above was very messy so I cleaned it up a bit. It now works on macOS and iOS!

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

$agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36';
$url = 'https://notmywebsite/remotevideo.mp4';
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); //Remote video might need it to get proper response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

$info = curl_exec($ch);
$filesize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
$end = $filesize - 1;

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    //If ranges are requested, perform a reg match and extract them
    preg_match('/bytes=(\d+)-(\d+)?/', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches);
    
    $fr = intval($matches[1]);
    $sr = is_null($matches[2]) ? $end : intval($matches[2]);
    $headers = array("Range: $matches[0]");

    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    header("Content-Range: bytes {$fr}-{$sr}/{$filesize}");

    //Here we set the headers (ranges) for the remote video request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
exit;

?>
```